# Rasterio: ValueError: width and height must be > 0

Tags: python, gdal, geopandas, rasterio

I trying to crop a geotiff image using `rasterio` with a geopandas `df` but I get an error if I use `crop=True`

```
src = 'myFile.tiif'
clipped_array, clipped_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, [mapping(df['geometry'][0])], crop=True)

ValueError: width and height must be > 0
```

it works if I don't use the option `crop=True`

```
clipped_array, clipped_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, [mapping(df['geometry'][0])])
```

Comment: How big is your polygon? Especially compared to the resolution of your geotiff. How many pixels are covered?

Comment: I've encountered this error before when accidentally applying a mask that didn't overlap the image at all. When you say "it works if I don't use...", does the result returned actually show any masking applied?

Comment: @jdmcbr it returns the clipped array with the size of the original array

Comment: @emax In that case, it is hard to see what's going on without seeing your geotiff and the geometry you're trying to mask with.